# How can I maintain PWM output while still performing other tasks?

Tags: pwm

I want to generate a PWM signal that I can turn on and off with a button press without using interrupts.  Is there a way to keep the PWM output going while running other processes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PWM just runs once started. It's all managed by a completely separate bit of silicon inside the chip.

Once you have done `analogWrite(...)` the PWM will just keep going until you tell it otherwise.

Comment: I was running this with Serial plotter yesterday and for some reason it kept interrupting the PWM when I was reading one of the analog channels.  I finally tested on an oscilloscope and it does work. Thanks!